# Expression Web: Shortcut doesn't point to an exe file, but I want to use it to edit

Tags: windows, editor, exe, shortcut, lnk

**Problem:** I have to support users who need to edit web pages. Some of these web pages exist only as textarea controls. Fortunately, there is a firefox plugin that allows the user to open the textarea in a default text editor. Unfortunately, this plugin requires you to point to the EXE file of the text editor you want to invoke.

This is a reasonable requirement, but @#$%^ Microsoft Expression Web is one of those applications whose shortcut .lnk file does not appear to point to a real EXE file. If there is an EXE file somewhere, it's hidden.

**Question:**
How can I locate the actual EXE file so people can configure Microsoft Expression web to be their editor of choice?

**Update:** I should have emphasized that I was looking for a way to automate this via script or batch file (hence the SO posting, in case anyone's "not-programming-related" spidey sense was tingling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my executable in the following location:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Expression\Web Designer\EXPRWD.EXE
```

I'm not sure if that gives you what you need, but you can always have your users (or programmatically) search for EXPRWD.EXE and go from there.